# invoke throws IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, reflection

I know there have been a lot of questions about reflection. I have read every one of them but the answer to my problem doesn't come up.

Here I have the following code

```
Method fn = Class.forName("paramopt.ParamOpt")
                 .getDeclaredMethod("Fn", double[].class);
```

The method `fn(double[] x)` is a function declared on the `ParamOpt` class as `public static`. It is invoked this way

```
 y[n] = (double) fn.invoke(new Object[]{start});
```

where `start` is a `double` array. And there is where I get

> `IllegalArgumentException`: wrong number of arguments message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args) { ... }
```

You passed no arguments to the `invoke` method.

The first parameter is in charge of an instance to invoke this method on. Since the method is `static`, you should pass `null` there.

The next parameter is a *varargs* parameter which presents actual method parameters. Here you go with a double array.

---

The answer is gonna be:

```
fn.invoke(null, new Object[]{start});
```

or simply

```
fn.invoke(null, start);
```

---

According to [the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-), an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown

> if the method is an instance method and the specified object argument is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying method (or of a subclass or implementor thereof); if the number of actual and formal parameters differ; if an unwrapping conversion for primitive arguments fails; or if, after possible unwrapping, a parameter value cannot be converted to the corresponding formal parameter type by a method invocation conversion.

---

In addition, ["15.12.4.4 Locate Method to Invoke"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.12.4.4) might be helpful.